# Combine multiple columns in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table from multiple columns in an existing table.
I need to combine or merge the data from multiple columns into just one column in the new table.

The original table

```
order_id | item_1_id | item_2_id | item_3_id
```

The table i need to create

```
order_id | item_id
```

I can create the table using

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
AS SELECT ...
```

but have no idea how to merge to `item_id` columns.

Any help?

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you want to get for it

Comment: Use `UNION` to combine queries that select each item_id column.